# Monotouch - Change View Title Background Color

Tags: xamarin.ios

Hy guys,

I have this view and I wonder how to change its title background color. This code here just change view's body background color:

```
var invoices = new MainInvoicesView(this);
invoices.Title = "Invoices";
invoices.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
```

Any ideas?

Regards,
Claudio

Answer (score 1):

What type of view is this? UIViews do not have a Title property, so you're obviously creating a different kind of view.

If you have a UILabel called TitleLabel in your view, and it's public, you should be able to just call:

```
invoices.TitleLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

Comment: Actually this is a UIViewController, sorry about my mistake. And there's no TitleLabel property too.

Comment: Right, there's no TitleLabel, because there are no labels in a simple UIView. My guess is that your MainInvoicesView inherits from UIView and adds a label to it. In that case, to change that label's background, you do "MyLabel.BackgroundColor = color". It's hard to answer this any better without knowing your code, though.